# Division of a square and value of a disk

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

[Full disclosure] I asked this question on math.stackexchange with little success : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866295/division-of-a-square-and-value-of-a-disk

I cam across this problem and I really don't know how to solve it.

So you start with a square that has value 1. You divide this square in 4 so that each new square has a new value, as given by the following picture :

[image]

Then you divide again each square in 4 new squares by the same process, so that you obtain the following picture and data :

[image]

Now put a circle inside the square :

[image]

If you repeat the process of dividing each square in 4, each new square having a new value, what is the value of the disk ?

I wrote a program allowing me to compute the value of the region outside the disk : I started with a square divided by $8 \times 8$ new squares and stopped at $2^{27} \times 2^{27}$.

Here is the output of the algorithm giving the approximation of the value of the disk (it is 1- approximation of the region outside the disk)

9.000000000e-01

8.144000000e-01

7.626000000e-01

7.292020000e-01

7.088800000e-01

6.973523000e-01

6.918611000e-01

6.885892690e-01

6.869197714e-01

6.859950674e-01

6.855135614e-01

6.852518648e-01

6.851172864e-01

6.850433926e-01

6.850051560e-01

6.849844363e-01

6.849737746e-01

6.849678775e-01

6.849649240e-01

6.849632929e-01

6.849624579e-01

6.849620047e-01

6.849617754e-01

6.849616479e-01

6.849615847e-01

I was not able to find an explicit formula for the limit (does it exist ?).

I also tried an exponential regression on the data but I was not really satisfied.

Any hint ?

[Added] I tried several configurations where I changed the parameters (values of the small squares) but I was not able to find anything...

Comment: If you expect your solution to be a simple linear expression in $\pi$, then $$\frac{3}{5}\pi-\frac{6}{5}\approx0.68495559$$ might be a reasonable guess.

Comment: The Fourier transform of the measure on the square can be written as an infinite product whose terms are Fourier transforms of weighted sums of $4$ delta functions, all rescaled copies of the original. The Fourier transform of the uniform measure on the disk is known and related to a Bessel function. The integral of the product of these gives an expression for the measure inside the circle.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching did you find this value with the help of a particular method ?

Comment: @user33624 This tool can guess what your number is.  http://mrob.com/pub/ries/

Comment: I used the LLL implementation of pari/gp: 
    lindep([.684961,1,Pi],flag=4)
gives
    [-5, -6, 3].

Comment: Wouldn't it be natural to first compute the sum over the entire square, rather than over the disk in the square?

Comment: The sum over the square would just be 1 right? The unnaturalness of the circle is what is making this problem difficult it seems.

Comment: @DouglasZare I think the difficulty lies in determining the several infinite products, doesn't it ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. It's not hard to write down the infinite product, and to evaluate it accurately at a point since it converges geometrically. It's like the Fourier transform of the Cantor measure, which looks like $\prod_i \cos x/3^i $. Then you can perform numerical integration. This doesn't mean you can tell if the integral of the product with the Fourier transform of a disk has a closed form expression. I'm not sure if it is more efficient at approximating the measure than using the quad-tree approach.

Comment: Yes, the infinite product at a point is easy to write down. If you write the coordinates of the point in base 2, the digits tell you if you have to multiply by 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 or 0.4. The problem is to sum all these infinite products inside the circle. The constraint that you have to impose is unnatural since the circle is breaking the scaling symmetry of the problem.

Comment: @Victor Godet: I was referring to the infinite product for the Fourier transform of the measure on the square.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Since the measure (or rather its density) is an infinite product in a natural way, I don't quite understand how you obtain an infinite product for the FT. I would expect an infinite convolution.

Comment: @Christian Remling: The measure on the square is an infinite convolution of measures supported on $4$ points each with weights $0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4$, just as the Cantor measure is an infinite convolution of measures supported on $2$ points each with weights $0.5,0.5$. The scaling factor for the $i$th summand is $1/3^i$ for the Cantor measure and $1/2^i$ here.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Thanks for the clarification. It seems you pay a price for this approach though, at the end, when we have to *convolve* (rather than multiply) with $\widehat{\chi_D}$.

Comment: Yes, that's why I commented rather than answered.

Comment: I think it should be easy (but tedious) to show that a limit exists, by showing that the total "value" of the little squares intersecting the boundary of the disc tends to 0. However, I see no indication that the limit should have a closed-form expression.

Comment: According to http://www.dices.net/spain/map-Caceres-Benavente-403990 the longitude of Benavente is $-6.84961$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis It is a monotonously decreasing sequence, since dividing squares never increases values, bounded below trivially by zero, so it is convergent.